# Call create method from index page - Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, rails7

I have a Document model and I'm looking **to create** a Document **by clicking a button that send some params from my index page**.
I want to do this whithout passed in the **'new'** page.

**What I want to do exactly is :** I click the button, that create my model with params passed, then redirect to the edit page to custom this document

---

In my index view I use this button : `<%= button_to "Edit", {:controller => "documents", :action => "create", :name=>"doc_name", :user_id=> current_user.id}, :method=>:post%>`

And in my document_controller I have this :

```
def create
@document = Document.new(document_params{params[:user_id]})

respond_to do |format|
  if @document.save
    flash.now[:notice] = "Document créé avec succès."

    format.turbo_stream do
      render turbo_stream: [turbo_stream.append("documents", partial:"documents/document", locals: {document: @document}),
        turbo_stream.update("content-d", partial:"documents/table"),
        turbo_stream.replace("notice", partial: "layouts/flash")]
    end
    format.html { redirect_to document_path(@document), notice: "Document was successfully created." }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @document }
    
  else
    format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def document_params
  params.fetch(:document, {}).permit(:doc_type, :number, :name, :total_ttc, :user_id)
end
```

Is there someone who can guide me to do this ?

Thank you all

---

### **UPDATE**

I just change my button_to for this one :

```
      <%= button_to "Edite", {:controller => "documents", :action => "create", :document=>{:name=>"doc_name", :user_id=> current_user.id}}, :method=>:post, class:"btn-primary" %>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your best chance of getting the right help and the right answer is to be as specific about your problem as possible. Try to post the specific issue or error or hangup you're having.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to:

1. Click a button
2. Have a new Document be created
3. Be redirected to the Edit view of that new Document

If you never need to land on `DocumentsController#new`, then you can just have the final action of `DocumentsController#new` be to `redirect_to` `DocumentsController#edit` for that `document`.

If you want to preserve the normal role of `DocumentsController#new`, just create a new route and controller action, e.g. `DocumentsController#create_from_index`

Then you can have a form (with a submit button) on your Index page that POSTs to your new route.

Using a form is your easiest method. If you don't want to use a form, you'll need to AJAX the button data to a controller action, which is a bit more complicated ([but still very doable](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/))

For example:

```rb
# routes
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :documents do
    collection do
      post 'create_from_index'
    end
  end
end
```

```
# documents_controller
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def index
    # do your index stuff here

    @new_document = Document.new
  end

  def create_from_index
   # get the params from the form submission (or AJAX request)
   if Document.create(document_params)
     # successful creation
     redirect_to action: :edit
   else
    # do something about errors
    render :index
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment
I decide to keep default routes and I've modified the create method.
Moreover, I just modify my button_to like this : 
`<%= button_to "Edite", {:controller => "documents", :action => "create", :document=>{:name=>"doc_name", :user_id=> current_user.id}}, :method=>:post, class:"btn-primary" %>`
And it's work !